# Comparing elements inside a list in c#

Tags: c#, list

I want to `compare` elements inside a single `List` in `C#`. I need to check whether same data is there in list or not . Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Anything tried so far?

Comment: `bool contains = list.Any(item => condition(item));`

Comment: Are you wanting to get a report as to whether there are duplicate items, or clear out duplicates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, for example:

```
var collection = new List<double>(new double[] { 10, 20, 11, 10, 20, 44 });
var info = collection.GroupBy(e => e).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Count());
```

Here `info` contain a double value as a `key` and number of this number in `collection` as `value`.

And this construction you can use with any type of `List` elements.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the LINQ extention methods

here is an example of LINQ comparing lists:

```
   list<string>  arr1 = new list<string>(){ "A", "b", "C," };
   list<string>  arr2 = new list<string>(){ "A", "b", "C," };
```

Compare the above arrays with the SequentialEqual() Method

```
bool result = arr3.SequentialEqual(arr2);
```

The Boolean result will contain true as the items in both lists are equal

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to know if there is more than one item in the list has the same value you can use this function..

```
public bool HasSameData<T>(List<T> myList)
{
    return myList.Distinct().Count() != myList.Count();
}
```

note that this will work with any type.

```
void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    var myList2 = new List<int> {1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    Console.WriteLine(HasSameData(myList));
    Console.WriteLine(HasSameData(myList2));

    var myList3 = new List<String> {"hello","world","foo","bar"};
    var myList4 = new List<String> {"hello","foo","foo","bar"};

    Console.WriteLine(HasSameData(myList3));
    Console.WriteLine(HasSameData(myList4));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
True
False
True
```